# Code me a Jam!!

Tags: code-golf, music

On occasion I get a little blue and need a little music to cheer me up, but clicking the start button and finding my media player takes *sooooooo* long. I want a faster way to play a song.

**The challenge:**

Write a program that:

- Choose a song from my home directory *(so you don’t mix-up program sound 
  files with music)* *(this includes sub folders of the home directory)*.
- This song should be a random choice from all the media in my home folder. This doesn't need to be a perfect random, but I don't want to hear the same song multiple times. *(unless that's my only song ;)*
- To make it simple you should only look for files ending in `.mp3`.
- In the event that you find no music in my home dir, you should print `Sorry Joe, no Jams!` to stdout or closest equivalent *(btw my name isn't Joe ;)*
- The layout of my home folder will contain no infinite loops
- You should use system to play the song instead of using built in media playing APIs in your language *(i.e. I want the song to play in the default player for my system)*.
- I should be able to place this file anywhere on my computer *(e.g. my desktop or start folder)*
- Your answer should work on windows, multi-platform is a *(un-scored)* bonus

This is code golf so the shortest program in bytes wins!!

Comment: What is your home dir?

Comment: It will differ from computer to computer, so you should use a builtin in your land to determine that. (e.g. in python `os.path.expanduser('~')`)

Comment: Lol, I meant lang, not land

Comment: waiting for an answer in CJam :)

Comment: May I post a theoretical answer? I haven't used Windows in years, but I _think_ I know an answer. It won't be golfed because I don't know that I can actually test it.

Comment: Go ahead, If I know how to use it I can try to test it for you. Otherwise some passer by might be nice and test it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### PowerShell, <strike>59</strike> 52 bytes

```
ii(ls -r./*.mp4|random);(,"Sorry Joe, no Jams!")[$?]
```

-7 byte golf improvements, thanks to Jaykul:

- Use `ii` (`Invoke-Item`) instead of `saps`
- No need to use `Get-` in `Get-noun` commandlet names, it will be searched by default.
- No space needed after `-r`

---

Previously at 59 bytes

```
saps(ls -R ~/*.mp3|Get-Random);(,"Sorry Joe, no Jams!")[$?]
```

It will throw an error if there are no files, but it will print the message too.

Explanation:

- `saps` is an alias for Start-Process
- `ls` is an alias for Get-ChildItem
- `~` maps to the home directory, and `-R` is -Recurse
- Get-Random selects a random item from the pipeline.
- After trying to launch it, it uses the previous command exit value as an index into a two-item array which either does nothing, or returns the apology message.

Comment: Wow that is short, very nice!

Comment: You can shorten that to `ii(ls -r./*.mp4|random);(,"Sorry Joe, no Jams!")[$?]` or if you're not willing to assume PowerShell is in the home directory already (that's it's default), then add one character: `ii(ls -r ~/*.mp4|random);(,"Sorry Joe, no Jams!")[$?]`

Comment: @Jaykul Thanks! I can probably take `Get-` out of loads of my answers now.

Comment: save one more byte by replacing `ii(ls -r./*.mp4|random);` with `ls -r./*.mp4|random|ii;`

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>78</s> <s>75</s> 73

```
{0::'Sorry Joe, no Jams!'⋄⎕SH⍵,{⍵⊃⍨?≢⍵}⎕SH∊'dir/b '⍵'*.mp3'}'%HOMEPATH%\'
```

**Explanation**:

`{`...`}` unnamed function, wherein `⍵` represents whatever is to the right of the `}`
APL statements (separated by `⋄`) are executed leftmost first, but each statement is evaluated from right to left (no precedence rules), so each function gets whatever is to its right as argument
`0::` sets a trap for all errors to return the string instead
`∊'dir/b '⍵'*.mp3'` makes the three strings into a single string
`⎕SH` passes its argument to *cmd.exe*
`?≢⍵` random 1 ≤ integer  ≤ count (or 0 < float < 1 if count is 0)
`⍵⊃⍨` pick that element (floats are invalid indices, so an error is triggered here if count was 0)
`⍵,` prepends the home dir
`⎕SH` passes its argument to *cmd.exe*

Comment: I may be missing somthing, but where does it print "Sorry Joe, no Jams!" if no media is found? (full disclosure, I have no idea how APL works ;)

Comment: @JAtkin Yeah, I forgot. Fixed.

Comment: @JAtkin Do you wan't an explanation now, or was "I have no idea how APL works" only a joke about my mistake?

Comment: No, that was for real, I have no clue how APL works.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 178 bytes

```
import glob,os,random
try:os.startfile(random.choice([y for x in os.walk(os.getenv('HOMEPATH'))for y in glob.glob(os.path.join(x[0],'*.mp3'))]))
except:print"Sorry Joe, no Jams!"
```

Works on Windows, as per the spec.

Comment: Nice. I can confirm this works.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the `[]`. Also, if you only need it to work on Windows, can't you just replace the call to `os.path.join` with `x[0]+'\*.mp3'` or something like that? It looks overly portable for golf :)

Answer (score 1):

## Linux shell utilities, 74

Ok, so this one's not going to work on windows, but in case you decide to use a real OS (), here's what you could do in Linux:

```
find ~ -name \*.mp3|shuf|(read l&&xdg-open "$l"||echo Sorry Joe, no Jams!)
```

Comment: Hey! I actually like windows 10. But I also like bash...

Comment: I have a copy of bash and the unix utils installed on my windows 7 box.  So this could work on windows if you have it set up right.

Comment: Is it possible to decompile this to [Batsh](https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh)?

Comment: @dorukayhan Probably, though I don't see what it would gain, given the dependencies on GNU `find` and `shuf` and xdg-utils `xdg-open`.